# How to find uncovered functions from test coverage report in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I am writing unit test coverage for react. I got the following report for a file:

```
% Stmts : 100      
% Branch : 100      
% Funcs : 91.3       
% Lines : 100 
Uncovered Line #s : NIL
```

I could see from the lcov coverage that report generated that the number of functions covered are 21/23. Is there any way to find which are the 2 functions left?

Comment: It’s listed in the report so you can reference to them via the lines of files.

Comment: Not sure about where to see the lines as the line coverage is 100%. Can you provide any doc which could help to identify?

Comment: This default configuration of the report would show you the lines where are yet tested https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options

Comment: have you tried getting uncovered lines by running this command `yarn test --coverage  --watchAll` ?

Comment: Yes. There are no uncovered lines

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled here looking for an answer to the same question, and found it myself within the report file.

- open /coverage/lcov-report/index.html
- click on the filename link on the left
- uncovered function will be highlighted in red